# How to rearrange a list of object / items

Tags: c#, list, ado.net

I have a list of employees which I get from database. I need to rearrange the list of employees to have fairness.

for example If I have `List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();`

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    departments.Add(new Department(Convert.ToInt16(reader.GetString("Did"))));
    departments[count].Name = reader.GetString("DName");
    departments[count].MinEarlyShift = Convert.ToInt16(reader.GetString("Minearlyshift"));
    departments[count].MinLateShift = Convert.ToInt16(reader.GetString("Minlateshift"));
    departments[count].EarlyShiftStart = Convert.ToDateTime( (reader.GetString("Earlyshift")));
}
```

now I have list of employees which will always have james in index 0 carter in index 1

but I want to rearrange this so carter may have the index 0 for example. basically shuffle the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var randomizedList = from empin allemployees 
                     orderby rnd.Next()
                     select emp;
```

Comment: @user3501845: What **exactly** doesn't work?

Comment: var randomizedList = from empin allemployees 
                     orderby rnd.Next()
                     select emp;

Comment: @user3501845: I mean next: What was the expected result and what was the actual? Also move `new Random()` out of the method scope.

Comment: this code just give me invalid expression error and field but used like type and emp doesn't exist error

Comment: all I want to do is shuffle the index order of my list so when i do foreach loop it wont be the same value

Comment: dont worrry guys got it working